# WPF Reactive UI cast the object when binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, casting, reactiveui

I am trying two way binding using code behind the Reactive UI way, but my code is failing at runtime because of the cast from base class to derived classes.
both cast are failing:

```
this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => ((Property<String>)vm.Model.Properties["Name"]).PropertyValue, v => v.NameTextBox.Text);
```

Exception: ArgumentException: Property 'System.String PropertyValue' is not defined for type 'BaseProperty'( my base class)

```
 this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => ((vm.Model.Properties["Name"]) as Property<String>).PropertyValue, v => v.NameTextBox.Text);
```

Exception: NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression type: 'TypeAs'

Is there a way to fix this ? 
thanks

Comment: What's the type of your ViewModel property and its Model property? You need to cast to the correct type.

Comment: I am using a dictionnary <string , BaseProperty> and I am casting to a derived class Property<String> , the cast is working outside of the binding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve